# Event Proposal: Decide on Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, chat

Last day, TeX.SX had an event called `answer the unanswered` to create an opportunity for the questions which did not receive enough attention to be reviewed. The outcome was so interesting indeed. In my opinion, the event had such productive outputs:

1. Unanswered questions went under users review. Each user in the chat room, copies the link of the question which he think it needs more attention. The unanswered question then may

   - receive an answer,
   - edited to be more clear,
   - closed for reasons of moderation,
   - deleted.
2. Some discussions would be made to the questions and answers which did not receive enough up-votes.
3. If some posts are edited, other changes to their tags, minor grammatical errors, titles, etc. can be corrected and edited too without hesitation about bumping questions to the active list of questions just because of a minor edit.

In my opinion, such chat room events are really helpful for Academia too. We do not have so many unanswered question, but some of them can be updated and edited to receive more attention. Their tags can be updated during events so fast. Their existing answers can be reviewed by their posters too. The best feature would be the concentration of discussions and fast decision making on the posts. Also, as these events may happen once in month or on other regular time table, there would be less worries on bumping old questions to the top list. As, most of the users would know this is the time for editing questions and posts.

I think that, even five questions and answers be edited in such event, that would be a success for such event. We need to review the posts on our site to keep it fresh and up to date, with high quality and perfectly edited posts.

My proposal is to have a chat room event on Academia as described above. In the first step we can have an event to review unanswered questions and the next would be for closed questions, down-voted questions, etc. Also, I think that having such event for decision making on tags, their excerpts and wikis, their scope, elimination of tags with low number of questions, etc. will be useful.

Please post your opinions for and against such event, and if you think we should have such event; propose on when such event should be held or how it should be moderated to be a more productive chat room event for Academia.

Answer (score 1):

As this site is currently running at 98% answered, I don't think we've got any pressing need for such an event.

However, I do enjoy dipping into the unanswered pool myself occasionally to do solo essentially the same thing that you are suggesting we do as a group event.  If a few other people are like-minded, I'd enjoy making it a chat room event for the company.

---

Update: I think we're good.  My personal procrastination campaign has removed about 1/3 of the unanswered questions, bringing us up to 99% answered.

Comment: What about having such event for other review purposes (closed questions, tags, etc.), as described in the last paragraphs?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Sure, why not?  As long as there's a critical mass of 5-ish people who want to play, I'm in.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Go check out chat - I've tossed some of the unanswered up for handling.